# Custom Post Type pagination when CPT 'rewrite' rule and a page have the same slug

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, slug, rewrite-rules

I would like to achive the following link structure on my site:

1. /properties/ -> a `properties` page with `properties` CPT, page 1.
2. /properties/page/2 -> a `properties` page with `properties` CPT, page 2.
3. /properties/property-name -> a single `properties` page with a property details.

I have a Custom Post Type (CPT) called `property`. It's registered as following with the `rewrite` rule specified as `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'properties', 'with_front' => false)`:

```
function property_post_type_init() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Properties', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Property', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'property')
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'properties', 'with_front' => false),
    'query_var' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports' => array(
      'title',
      'editor',
      'revisions'
    )
  );
  register_post_type('property',$args);
```

I also have a page with the slug `properties` and the permalink structure is set as `/%category%/%postname%/`

On the `Properties` page I construct a new `WP_Query` object with the following arguments:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => $paged
);
return $args;
```

I use a custom pagination code (in functions.php) which generates pagination correctly with the correct urls:

```
<my-site>/properties/
<my-site>/properties/page/2/
<my-site>/properties/page/3/
```

However, when I click on any page in the pagination I get redirected to 404 page. I've expected the query params and they are the following:

```
[page] => 2
[property] => page
[post_type] => property
[name] => page
```

Which is not correct! I don't understand where these parameters are coming from:

```
[page] => 2
[property] => page
[name] => page
```

I'm sure it's something to do with the `rewrite` rule when registering a CPT.

How can I achive the following set up to work correctly:

1. A `properties` page that displays all `properties` custom post types posts with pagination.
2. A `properties` custom post type with `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'properties', 'with_front' => false)` rule.
3. Permalink of `/%category%/%postname%/` structure

So that I have the following link structure:

1. /properties/ -> a `properties` page with `properties` CPT, page 1.
2. /properties/page/2 -> a `properties` page with `properties` CPT, page 2.
3. /properties/property-name -> a single `properties` page with a property details.

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks,
Dasha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the page's slug to something else and changing your post type registration to this:

```
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'properties', 'with_front' => false),
    'query_var' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports' => array(
      'title',
      'editor',
      'revisions'
    )
  );
```

The operative new argument is `'has_archive'`. This is new in 3.1, and gives you a `/properties/`, `/properties/page/2`, etc. structure by default. Then flush your rewrite rules and see if that fixes it. You may also need to comment out any code you've written playing with the query or rewrite rules

Comment: After specifying `'has_archive' => true` the urls like `/properties/page/2` go to `archive.php` template.