# Redirect default pagination page to template page's pagination

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules

How do I redirect the default pagination pages such as **http://mywebsite.com/page/2** to a template page so it looks like **http://mywebsite.com/articles/page/2**

`articles` is a custom template page and not a CPT.

Created with /* Template Name: Articles */ and has the `articles` slug under Pages

Comment: Is 'articles' a CPT? If so it might be a small settings change in your post type arguments. Although this link is a different question, the answer might help? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15851/custom-post-type-pagination-when-cpt-rewrite-rule-and-a-page-have-the-same-slu

Comment: I edited my comment to clarify that it's a custom page template

Comment: To be fair you did say template originally, I didn't read well enough :) This feels like you need a custom rewrite and its not a strength of mine so I hope someone else will jump in and help. If you have tried anything so far, htaccess or wp_rewrite it might help you to elaborate further in your original question.